# How to do a lawn program that calculate the total metres entered by the user

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to do a program that will calculate the size of lawn - it will have 2 textboxes and a label `length * width = total metres`. My problem is that when I put in a decimal value it shows an error but when I put integer value on the text box it shows no error and calculates it and I did everything right my code looks like this

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim decLegth, decWidth, decSize As Decimal
        decLegth = Convert.ToDecimal(txtLength.Text)
        decWidth = Convert.ToDecimal(txtWidth.Text)
        decSize = decLegth * decWidth
        lblDisplay.Text = decSize.ToString("N2")
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: what error? And instead of use Decimal.Parse or better Decimal.TryParse.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely a culture problem. You see, in some countries decimals are separated by a **`,`** while others use the **`.`**.

This is how I set the culture of my application to Norwegian:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("nb-NO")
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("nb-NO")
```

So now, if i try convert i do like this:

```
Dim d As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal("10,0", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture)
```

Here's a [list of culture codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so you can find yours.

On the other hand, instead of `TextBox` you ought to use the [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control.
It exposes a decimal `Value` property of the displayed "text".

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Decimal` type for your variables, use `Double` instead.  The problem is probably when it tries to convert your text box string value to a Decimal.  Instead you do something like this:

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim decLegth, decWidth, decSize As Double
    decLegth = Convert.ToDouble(txtLength.Text)
    decWidth = Convert.ToDouble(txtWidth.Text)
    decSize = decLegth * decWidth
    lblDisplay.Text = decSize.ToString("N2")
```

Also, I actually don't have a VB compiler currently but you might have to convert the text box values to strings first, try both ways:

```
Convert.ToDouble(txtLength.Text.ToString());
```