# Converting string number to double

Tags: vb.net, string, casting

Hello I have a mysterious problem.

First I will show you the code that works. I used a new project to test my Problem, but here it works:

```
Public str As String
Public dbl As Double

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    str = 97.9
    dbl = CDbl(str)
    MsgBox(dbl)

End Sub
```

Output Msgbox ="97,9"

Now I show you the code which wont work. This is a code snippet from my Main Project.
xanswer...ElementAt(index).@similarity.ToString 
Is the response from the webservice I use and @similarity gives back a Strings with double or Integer values.

```
 Dim str As String = xanswer.<possibleduplicates>.<address>.ElementAt(index).@similarity.ToString
                Dim dbl As Double = CDbl(str)
                simlist.Add(dbl)
```

when I hover over str= "97.9" ok, but when I hover over dbl it gives me "979.0"
why is that? In the second variable it also uses a "." instead of a ","
any idea?

Comment: This is most likely a [culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.cultureinfo) problem. Please see my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20512614/1842065

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string number `97.9` is being converted to double, but in your current computer culture the points act as a thousands separator, and commas as decimals separator, and looks like you want the point to act as a decimal separator. Is a culture problem.

Try this:

```
str = "97.9"
dbl = Double.Parse(str, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Take a look at the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

By the way, you should use `Option Strict On` to prevent implicit conversions of types in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I got it working with this little method

```
Public Function toDouble(sim As String) As Double
    Dim dbl As Double = CDbl(sim.Replace(".", ","))
    Return dbl

End Function
```

Comment: why did I get a -1 ??